# colour is not Highlighted in listviewitem subitems

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using this code to hide the first three subitems of even numbers .

For ex

there are 2 listviewitem

1) 132 |123  |123 |123 |Buy |11 |11  |11  |11

2) 132 |123  |123 |123 |Sell|22 |22  |22  |22

I am displaying them like this in the listview

```
         132 |123  |123 |123 |Buy |11 |11  |11  |11 

                             |Sell|22 |22  |22  |22
```

I want to highlight the color of Buy as Green
 and sell as Red

I am using this code to display it is highlighting green but not for red

```
        int iRecords = 0;
        int iDate = 0;
        int iRecords1 = 0;
        using (var sr = File.OpenText(destination + "\\Calc.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            bool flag = true;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] reader2 = line.Split(',');
                string Date = reader2[0];
                string Name = reader2[1];
                string Sym = reader2[2];
                double Buy = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[3]);
                double Sell = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[4]);
                double rateBuy = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[5]);
                double rateSell = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[6]);


                ListViewItem lItem = new ListViewItem();

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    lItem = listviewrates.Items.Insert(iRecords, Date.ToString());
                    date.Text = Date;
                    lItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(Name.ToString());
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(Sym.ToString());
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(Buy.ToString(), Color.White, Color.Green, lItem.Font);
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(rateBuy.ToString());

                    i = 2;
                    iRecords++;
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    lItem = listviewTargets.Items.Insert(iRecords, "");
                    //iRecords = iRecords - 1;
                    lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                    lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(Sell.ToString(), Color.White, Color.Red, lItem.Font);
                    lItem.SubItems.Add(rateSell.ToString());

                    i = 0;
                    iRecords++;

                }


            }



        }
```

Can any one please say me how to highlight red color for sell.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your green items, you did:

```
lItem.useItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

You need to add the property for the red item, too, since lItem is a new object.

```
if (i == 2)
{
  lItem = listviewTargets.Items.Insert(iRecords, "");

  //Fix here:
  lItem.useItemStyleForSubItems = false;

  lItem.SubItems.Add("");
  lItem.SubItems.Add("");
  lItem.SubItems.Add(Sell.ToString(), Color.White, Color.Red, lItem.Font);
  lItem.SubItems.Add(rateSell.ToString());

  i = 0;
  iRecords++;
}
```